# Core scaffolding Oracle DB will give multiple ID(primary key's) as result

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

When I scaffold this Oracle DB (database -first) and it generates me all models, contexts, FK relations ect. But it gives me an error in the context when I start Querying.
(simple things as select * from (any Table))

> The follow error comes up.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> HResult=0x80131509
>
> Message=The properties 'Address.AddressId', 'Address.AddressItemId'
>   are configured to use 'Identity' value generator and are mapped to the
>   same table '[DBName].ADDRESS'. Only one column per table can be
>   configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' for properties
>   that should not use 'Identity'.
>
> Source=Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at
>   Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.OracleModelValidator.ValidateSharedColumnsCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1
>   mappedTypes, String tableName)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IModel
>   model)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)
>
> at
>   Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.OracleModelValidator.Validate(IModel
>   model)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ValidatingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.Validate()
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1()
>
> at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>
> at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
>   executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>
> at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>
> at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext
>   context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.b__7_2(IServiceProvider
>   p)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(IServiceCallSite
>   callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>
> at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
> at OracleConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\GitPlayGround\OracleConsoleApp\OracleConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 47

I need to use the FK connections in this complex structure.
I have no experience with Oracle, nor with Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.6, application core 2.2)
Can anyone advise me what to do, Can't find a clue to start to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

After a deep research, my colleague came with the solution.
In Oracle generated value's work different. With the database first it sets the data annotation ValueGeneratedOnAdd();.

This is not a working model and context.

So selective deleting this ValueGeneratedOnAdd() will result in a working result and solves the problem.